# Python: Is .avif handling possible?

Tags: python, image

I have a whole bunch of .avif images that i can't open with any program. I want to convert these files to something more conventional like .jpg but online converters won't let me convert 200 files. So is there any library that converts images? Or at least is possible to load these images into python so i can make some sort of image viewer?

Comment: it seems there is plugin for `pillow` to work with this format - [pillow-avif-plugin · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pillow-avif-plugin/)

Answer (score 11):

Module [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/) has extension [pillow-avif-plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pillow-avif-plugin/) which allows to read this format

```
pip install pillow-avif-plugin
```

```
from PIL import Image
import pillow_avif

img = Image.open('kimono.avif')
img.save('kimono.jpg')

#import PIL
#print(PIL.__version__)
```

---

I tested on Linux Mint, Python 3.8, Pillow 8.4.0 using image `'kimono.avif'` from GitHub repo: [link-u/avif-sample-images](https://github.com/link-u/avif-sample-images).

It seems `link-u` has also programs [cavif](https://github.com/link-u/cavif) and [davif](https://github.com/link-u/davif) to convert image directly in console/terminal.

---

`avif` is on list of supported format in [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) so you could use it also to convert all images in console/terminal using `*` in names - but this format doesn't work on my systems. Maybe it needs to install some library.

If it would work in `ImageMagick` then it should work also with Python module [Wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/).